# How to automatically search with out clicking Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

i have few text boxes and dropdown boxes in a search window,and when click search button it will display data on gridview based on value selection in controls.Now what i want is even without clicking on search button it will display data automatically in gridview based on control selection.How to achieve it.I am posting small snippet contains only text box.

#### UI

```
 <div>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </div>
 <div>
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
 </div>
 <div>
     <asp:GridView ID="grdresults" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
 </div>
```

#### CS

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LoadData();
            BindGrid();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The above  LoadData(); method will create the search criteria (`where` clause for oracle query) and will get data in to `datatable` which will be in `session`,Then BindGrid(); will assign data to `grdresult` gridview.Search is working fine by clicking the button,but i want it in an automated way

Comment: [TextBox.AutoPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx) could help you submit on ENTER - unless you want to refresh your grid for every single character entered into your TextBox.

Comment: i dont want to click enter button which already i achieved by clicking Search button

Comment: Do you want it to search every time the TextBox changes?

Comment: @Filburt then TextChanged event is best, may be i have to use update panel also???

Comment: @kalamazoowho yes

Comment: Then just add your code the to a TextChanged event. It will trigger every time the text changes in that Text Box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UI

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" TextChanged="txtFirstName_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

#### CS

```
protected void txtFirstName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        LoadData();
        BindGrid();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is when I clear the textbox , the gridview will be cleared

Comment: If you want to clear the text box without clearing the gridview, then you need to implement some kind of "save" method that sets the gridview and disables the textChanged listener. This will allow you to save what is in the gridview without updating. Unfortunately, this will require a button or some other way to trigger the flag.

Comment: No my friend I have fixed this bug by other trick :)

Comment: I mean it’s not really a bug if it’s the intended use. Care to share your approach?